# Not your typical triple scalar product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products, matrix-equations, clifford-algebras

I've reduced a problem I'm working on to a rather interesting relationship between three vectors. The result looks quite a bit like an inner product on three vectors, and I'm having trouble figuring out what to make of it:

In a finite-dimensional complex vector space $V$, and vectors $x,y \in V$ and fixed positive real scalars $c_1, \ldots, c_n$, and an orthonormal basis $\mathcal{B} = \{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ such that
$$
x = x_{1}e_1 + \ldots + x_ne_n, \qquad y= y_1e_1 + \ldots + y_n e_n
$$
I need to understand the conditions (preferably as much in terms of $x$ and $y$ as possible) under which
$$
\frac{\bar{x}_1 y_1}{c_1} + \ldots + \frac{\bar{x}_n y_n}{c_n} = 0
$$

For some context I arrived at this by a Hadamard "division" of signals respresented by $x$ and $y$, by $(\sqrt{c_1},\ldots , \sqrt{c_{n}})$ and then taking their inner product, but I strongly get the sense that this second form is of some importance. It's essentially an orthogonality condition of sorts between $x,y$ and the vector $(\frac{1}{c_1},\ldots , \frac{1}{c_n})$. Or else it can be viewed like a sequilinear form of sorts, with $C$ being the diagonal matrix with entries $\frac{1}{c_i}$ and then
$$
x^{*}Cy = 0.
$$
I suspect this might be something that would crop up in Clifford algebra or some other kind of alien technology. But I'd be interested in any insight that anyone's got. If possible, I would love to have equivalent conditions of some sort regarding these vectors, or their coefficients in $\mathcal{B}$, or even their relative magnitudes, perhaps.

Comment: $\bar{x}_k$ is the (complex) conjugate of $x_k$?

Comment: It's just an inner product slightly different from the usual inner product.

Comment: What is "your father's triple scalar product"?  Is there also "your mother's triple scalar product"?  What about your brother's, your niece's, etc?

Comment: I agree that there's no need to use gender-specific language (that's irrelevant to the problem anyway) in an academic field that already has significant problems pushing women away. However jokingly you intended it, please change the title.

Comment: It's the usual dot (or more exactly sesquilinear) product with axes rescaled in this way : $x_i \longleftrightarrow \dfrac{x_i}{\sqrt{c_i}}$, nothing more...

Comment: I've taken the liberty of changing the title to something that is presumably equivalent and far more tasteful. It is also less eye catching, but it was eye catching for the wrong reasons in the first place.

Comment: @Travis I was terribly unclear: I do recognize this as a sesquilinear form, and I will swear up and down that I'm entirely capable by dividing each $e_i$ by ${c_i}^{-1/4}$ as needed to get the same reconstruction.

What I am trying to do is attempt to describe when (in terms of the orthonormal basis) this orthogonality will hold. Certainly if I fix one $x$, then as $y$ varies the null set is just the perpendicular $n-1$-plane to $y$. But for any two given vectors to be orthogonal, are there any worthwhile equivalent conditions, maybe in terms of the $c_{i}$'s?

Comment: @JeanMarie I tried to be too general in presenting this. I attempted to clear up what I'm asking in a comment above.

Comment: @gt6989b Yes, and " * " is the conjugate transpose here.

Comment: @Batominovski Well, *my* father never had an inner product. He settled for the taxicab metric, but I guess he was just square like that.

My *mother* grew up under the discrete metric. Finest woman I knew...

Comment: A conic section with equation $A x^2+B y^2 + C x y + D x + E y + F =0$ can be represented with a 3×3 symmetric matrix ${\rm C}$ such that with points ${\bf p}=(x,y,1)$ the following is true $${\bf p}^\top {\rm C} \,{\bf p}=0$$ This all looks similar to your situation, but for $\mathbb{R}^2$ cartesian space, or $\mathbb{R}^3$ projective space.